# Refer to Excel cell in Table by header name and row number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to refer to a cell in an excel table by using the table header name and the row number using VBA.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In your example, something like this:

```
Dim tb As ListObject
'assumes Table is the first one on the ActiveSheet
Set tb = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
MsgBox tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(2, tb.ListColumns("header4").Index)
```

Comment: You can also refer to the table name like so:     ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

Comment: Also refer as `Range("TableName").ListObject`

Answer (score 21):

A shorter answer is:

```
MsgBox [MyTable].Cells(2, [MyTable[MyColumn]].Column)
```

Much cleaner and easier!

Comment: This -> [MyTable[MyColumn]] is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 7):

Is there any reason one should avoid using this method?

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyWksht").Range("TableName[ColumnTitle]").Cells(RowNumber)`

Seems the simplest answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that @Salam Morcos solution will not give a proper answer. If table starts from  cell `A2` statment `[MyTable[FirstColumnName]].Column` would give value of 2. Proper solution would be:

```
MsgBox [MyTable].Cells(2, [MyTable].Column-[MyTable[MyColumn]].Column + 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

It is as simple as this. If you call by the name of the column, then the column index will be 1 for that range so:

```
msgbox ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("header4").DataBodyRange(2,1).value
```

**Note** that the column index in DataBodyRange is always 1, because there is 1 column in the column you refer to by its name

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write it short:

```
[MyTable[header4]].Rows(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler, and dynamic:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WorkSheet_Name").Range("Table_Name").Rows(Table_row_number).Select
```

Comment: How does this select the cell in the column "header4"?

Answer (score 0):

I made this function which could be used as follows to return the value you want.

Usage example:
GetTableValue(yourTableName, "ID", 3, "header4")

```
Function GetTableValue( _
  ByRef table As ListObject, _
  ByVal columnNameForKeyValue As String, _
  ByVal keyValue As Variant, _
  ByVal columNameForReturnValue As String _
) As Variant

  Dim rowIndex As LongPtr
  Dim columnIndex As LongPtr

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

  rowIndex = Application.Match(keyValue, 
  table.ListColumns(columnNameForKeyValue).DataBodyRange, 0)

  columnIndex = table.ListColumns(columNameForReturnValue).Index

  GetTableValue = table.DataBodyRange.Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).value

  Exit Function

  ErrorHandling:

  GetTableValue = "Error: Review inputs"

End Function
```