# Refer to Excel cell in filtered Table

Tags: excel, vba

### I'm trying to refer to a cell in an Excel table, which filtered by date (today), and then paste something off the clipboard. I've tried a lot and nothing is working so far. How can I do it?

Here's the table:
[image: Table Screenshot]

As you can see the currently only visible (todays) row, is row 38 which will change tomorrow into row 39, since it's filtered to the current day (today). So it's sort of a dynamic cell.

Here are my attempts:

```
Workbooks("Analysis Sheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Data Entry").Range("[@[AC-47]]").Select.Paste
Workbooks("Analysis Sheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Data Entry").Range(Range("I1"), Range("I1").End(xlDown)).Select.Paste

Workbooks("Analysis Sheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Data Entry").Rows(1).Find(what:="[@[AC-47]]").Select.Paste

Workbooks("Analysis Sheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Data Entry").ListObjects.ListColumns("[@[AC-47]]").DataBodyRange.Paste
Workbooks("Analysis Sheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Data Entry").ListObjects.ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange.Paste

Workbooks("Analysis Sheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Data Entry").DataBodyRange(1, 9).Select.Paste
Workbooks("Analysis Sheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Data Entry").BodyRange(1, 9).Select.Paste

Range("Data_Entry_Table[@[AC-47]],[Column9]]").Select.Paste
```

I have also tried ["Refer to Excel cell in Table by header name and row number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811431/refer-to-excel-cell-in-table-by-header-name-and-row-number) furthermore ending the code lines without `.Select`, so only with `.Paste`, neither worked.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Select` returns a variant data type, not an object. Try like `Range("Data_Entry_Table[@[AC-47]],[Column9]]").Select` then `Sheets("Data Entry").Paste` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: When you must use a discontinued range,  like the visible cells of a specific range, you must use range Areas... I will post a piece of code, which I think will solve your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testPasteForToday()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rngVis As Range, ar As Range, refCell As Range
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
   Set rngVis = sh.UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
     For Each ar In rngVis.Areas
        Set refCell = ar.Find(Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd"), ar.cells(1, 1), xlValues, , , xlNext, False)
        If Not refCell Is Nothing Then
            refCell.Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
     Next
End Sub
```

You can use the next code without any preliminary filtering. It also works on filtered area since the cell to paste in, is visible... I mean, instead of the above code, specially created to deal with a filtered discontinuous range (Areas):

```
Sub testPaste_bis()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, refCell As Range
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set refCell = sh.UsedRange.Find(Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd"), sh.Range("H1"), xlValues, , , xlNext, False)
    If Not refCell Is Nothing Then
        refCell.Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Help64mycat: Did you find time to check the above code?

Comment: I've tried testPasteForToday() and it did paste but into the G Column wrongly for some reason, the row was right. I need it to be pasted into the l Column and not into the H Column where Date is located, I will edit my post to make that more clear tomorrow and I will also try testPaste_bis(). This has been useful so far thank you for your contribution!

Comment: @Help64mycat: This may happen only if a today date also exists in column F:F, on the same row. No matter of format. Does it exist? Even if it does, I can adapt the code to search only in column H:H... I thought that Today date exists only once on the processed worksheet.

Comment: It did exist in E:E, which is wasn't intentional, I fixed and removed it, no adaptation of your code needed

Weirdly though trying testPasteForToday() this time, got this error:
"The maximum number of data series per chart is 255" after nothing has been pasted this time. I checked the clipboard and it's not because nothing has previously been copied.
(I do have charts from that table in another sheet within the same workbook)

The testPaste_bis() attempt showed this error 
"End If without block"
I tried removing 'End if' which also didn't work
I will try more troubleshooting tomorrow.

Comment: @Help64mycat: The above code cannot raise such an error, I think. I am referring to the first one. If not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion (with the code inside), putting here a link to it (OneDrive, Easyupload.io etc.)? in the second code I deleted a `Debug.Print` line but, by mistake, I also delete another one above it. Now corrected the code...

Comment: @Help64mycat: Downloaded the file, but it is a .xlsx file, without any code, with a single page, not having  any date on it. What is supposed to be checked in such a workbook?

Comment: @Help64mycat: Now it is xlsm workbook. I will look at it  and reply in a few minutes...

Comment: @Help64mycat: It looks, `Find` function is not able to find date in special/custom format where regional settings does not match this cells format involving words. I mean, your cells format is "[$-en-DE,1]dddd, mmmm d", but because of my regional settings which are different, Excel cannot find a match. Are you from USA? If not, you maybe face the same type of problem... I adapted the above code to work for a standard format: "yyyy-mm-dd". Try formatting the column in discussion in this way, please. If not convenient, I do  not have time now to find a workaround (if would be possible...).

Comment: My date is indeed setted to the USA Format. It's no problem for me to format it according to your suggestion "yyyy-mm-dd", I will try it immediately, thank you.

Comment: With joy and gratitude after all this effort, I can say yes it does. Thank you, I hope anyone dealing with something similar comes across this to find to find the solution.

Comment: @Help64mycat: Glad I could help! The problem was the peculiar date format combined with your regional settings. With a similar format, but matching my regional settings, VBA could find a match... But everything well when ends well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
With Workbooks("Analysis Sheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Data Entry")

    myRow = .Range("H2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Row
    myCol = 9

    .Cells(myRow,myCol).Select
    .Paste

End With
```

This selects the visible cells *after* filtration, and returns the row of the first one. Note that the header cell is ignored by starting the range from the second row (`Range("H2")`).

Comment: I've tried this also and it just showed an error again unfortunately

Comment: It worked when I tried it, bit I didn't use your sheets, so the error might be in the references.

Comment: You are right the error shows "Invalid or unqualified reference" and then it marks the .Range so it may be due to .Range("H2"), did you use a filter in your test sheet that is set to "today" ? Because in my current view it should have selected the 40th row, tomorrow it should be the 41st row since it updates to the current day, daily.

Comment: @Help64mycatl; you will have to run the macro daily to reflect this. I used a filter but just a basic one. Don't include the header cell (the one with the dropdown) in your range, as it confuses `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.