# Referencing a Table header

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I have code, referencing the column number, to search a column for a string and retrieve the information in the cells of that row into textboxes on a UserForm.

How can it reference the column header instead of the column number?

I could do with this as I have the single UserForm for multiple tables on multiple sheets where the columns can differ.

The code for the column number. As an example to get me started the first table name is "kiln1tbl".

```vb
Dim srchrecord As String
srchrecord = Trim(dateTextBox.Value & ", " & timeTextBox.Value)
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = srchrecord Then
    flowTextBox.Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value
    densityTextBox.Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value
end if
Next
```

An example of a similar command that works.

```vb
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Worksheets("Kiln 1").ListObjects("kiln1tbl")
Intersect(.Range.Rows(1), tbl.ListColumns("material").Range.Columns(1)).Value
```

Comment: The code does not look like google app script to me, rather vb script. Is this Excel?

Comment: yes it is Excel

Comment: Perhaps here is the answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811431/refer-to-excel-cell-in-table-by-header-name-and-row-number

Answer (score 0):

### A Table Study

- This illustrates how to reference the various ranges (columns) and their elements (rows) in a table.
- Adjust the workbook, worksheet, table, and column titles.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TableStudy()
    
    ' Create a reference to the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ' Create a reference to the first table.
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
    ' Get the indexes of the columns.
    Dim cFlow As Long: cFlow = tbl.ListColumns("Flow").Index
    Dim cDensity As Long: cDensity = tbl.ListColumns("Density").Index
    ' Create a reference to the (table data body) range.
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = tbl.DataBodyRange
    ' Write the values of the range to an array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Debug.Print "Headers & Data" & vbLf
    
    ' Print the headers
    Debug.Print tbl.HeaderRowRange(1), tbl.HeaderRowRange(cFlow), _
        tbl.HeaderRowRange(cDensity)
    
    ' Print the data.
    Dim r As Long
    ' Loop through the rows of the array...
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Data(r, 1) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print Data(r, 1), Data(r, cFlow), Data(r, cDensity)
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Print some addresses.
    Debug.Print vbLf & "How to reference the various ranges of the columns"
    Debug.Print "Range Addresses"
    Debug.Print tbl.ListColumns(1).Range.Address, _
        tbl.ListColumns(cFlow).Range.Address, _
        tbl.ListColumns(cDensity).Range.Address
    Debug.Print "Header Row Range Addresses"
    Debug.Print tbl.HeaderRowRange(1).Address, _
        tbl.HeaderRowRange(cFlow).Address, _
        tbl.HeaderRowRange(cDensity).Address
    Debug.Print "Data Body Range Addresses"
    Debug.Print tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Address, _
        tbl.ListColumns(cFlow).DataBodyRange.Address, _
        tbl.ListColumns(cDensity).DataBodyRange.Address
    
    Debug.Print vbLf & "How to reference the various ranges of the table"
    Debug.Print "Range", "HeaderRow", "DataBody"
    Debug.Print tbl.Range.Address, tbl.HeaderRowRange.Address, _
        tbl.DataBodyRange.Address
    
End Sub
```

Applying the previous to your first example could result in something like this:

```
Dim srchrecord As String
srchrecord = Trim(dateTextBox.Value & ", " & timeTextBox.Value)

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)

Dim cFlow As Long: cFlow = tbl.ListColumns("Flow").Index
Dim cDensity As Long: cDensity = tbl.ListColumns("Density").Index

Dim rg As Range: Set rg = tbl.DataBodyRange
Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value

Dim r As Long
For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
    If Data(r, 1) = srchrecord Then
        flowTextBox.Value = Data(r, cFlow)
        densityTextBox.Value = Data(r, cDensity)
    End If
Next r
```