# Excel vba 16.65 mac osx cannot write string with special characters to a table cell

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a table where I store user password in column 2 ("Password").
I have created a simple routine that encrypts with some special characters the original password string.
If I take the routine output and I manually paste it into the table cell, everything is working ok.
When I try to do it programmatically, the old non encrypted value stays there unchanged.

```
...
Set tblUtenti = Tabelle.ListObjects("Utenti_Tabella")
...
tblUtenti.DataBodyRange.Value2(UtenteRecNo, 2) = NuovaPwd
...
```

Any solution?

Comment: `DataBodyRange.Value2(UtenteRecNo, 2) = NuovaPwd` has no meaning in any OS... Please, try explaining **in words** what you try accomplishing. What `UtenteRecNo, 2` should mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811431/refer-to-excel-cell-in-table-by-header-name-and-row-number

Comment: If `UtenteRecNo` is the column name and you try pasting on the second row, please try: `tblUtenti.DataBodyRange.Cells(2, tblUtenti.ListColumns("tblUtenti").Index).value2 = NuovaPwd`...

Comment: It should be `ListColumns("UtenteRecNo").Index`... The clipboard was not empty when tried copying UtenteRecNo.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me.
The correct advice was provided me by @FunThomas.
Correct command is tblUtenti.DataBodyRange(UtenteRecNo, 2).Value2 = NuovaPwd

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with special characters or MacOS. Your syntax of accessing the cell is wrong:

The statement `tblUtenti.DataBodyRange.Value2(UtenteRecNo, 2)` is reading all values of the table (`DataBodyRange`) into a 2-dimensional array. After that you modify one of the values inside the array. However, the array is no longer attached to the table itself, so the new value is not put into the cell.

Simply change the line to `tblUtenti.DataBodyRange(UtenteRecNo, 2).Value2 = NuovaPwd`

Comment: You are right, shame on me!
Changing my command with your made everything working as expected. Many Thanks!