# Insert a Comment into Cell using [table_name[header]] - Method

Tags: excel, vba

How can i insert a Comment using this Method:

```
[tbl_name[header]].rows(x).AddComment "Comment" '<- Does not work
[tbl_name[header]].rows(x).AddComment.Text "Comment" '<- Does not work
[tbl_name[header]].rows(x).AddComment Text:="Comment" '<- Does not work
With [tbl_name[header]].rows(x).AddComment 
    .Text "Comment" '<- Does work but not by every insert
End With
```

Any suggestion? Best regards

I Already have been trying using this [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811431/refer-to-excel-cell-in-table-by-header-name-and-row-number) but does not help or i can´t help myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
With [tbl_name[header]].rows(x)
    .Value = "Something"
    .AddComment "Some Comment"
End With
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).